# Shell script execution using action script 3.0

Tags: shell, actionscript, execute

I have shell script command , i would like to execute it using action script 3.0.
Here is my shell script below

```
#!/bin/sh
set backslash_quote = "yes"
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set visible of some item of\
 ( get processes whose name = \"Terminal\" ) to false"
```

Comment: I am also trying to pass commands to the shell from actionscript.
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32126404/5248892) I believe that this will help. It explains how to execute a python file. Just subsistute it for your shell script.

Answer (score -1):

Where is the shell script that you are trying to execute? Is it on the server that the Flash will be hosted from or is it on the end users computer?

If it is on the server then you will need to set up a service to do this. Personally, I recommend PHP.

If it is on the end users machine, take a look at [Creating Hidden File with Flex/AIR on Win](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489952/creating-hidden-file-with-flex-air-on-win/10491378#10491378). The answer in that link will give you an idea how to execute scripts on the users machine... Though I am pretty sure that will only work in AIR apps.