# Command Line Calls in Adobe Flash

Tags: linux, shell, flash, actionscript, debian

Is there a way to make a call to the command line, (On Debian) from ActionScript in Adobe Flash? For example, execute files:

`python update.py`

Steps for this on Windows would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Adobe Air version 2.0.x on Linux, you can use the NativeProcess() class (assuming your update.py is flagged as executable (a+x):

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("update.py"); 
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file; 
var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(); 
processArgs.push("AnUpdateArgument"); 
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs; 
process = new NativeProcess(); 
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo); 
public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{ 
    var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput; 
    var data:String = stdOut.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable); 
    trace("Got: ", data); 
}
```

[Communicating with native processes in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html)

Note: You can not do this via a browser based SWF

Comment: I'm not using air. Will this still work for native swf?

Comment: No, access native processes, filesystem, etc.. are AIR based only. Due to security sandboxing those APIs are not available for a browser based Flash/SWF.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

I see I can substitute the value of the file variable for what ever I need executed.That's fine if I want to execute that file. What about a simple command like `cd MyDir` or `mkdir ThisAndThat` Just plain old passes to the shell will be great. I am also using GNU Gnash with an SFW.

Comment: Each time you call "process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo); " you are getting a new shell, so can you "cd MyDir"?, sure but the shell's state is gone after the cmd completes. Something like "mkdir ThisAndThat" can be done with Air's File.createDirectory(). If there are a series of shell cmd's you can either call an existing script or start "sh" as a process and pass a string of arguments just like you would from a bash/zsh/etc.. one-liner (i.e.:  sh -c "cd ~/script; ./fixme.sh; cd ~/foo; ./python-script.py")

Comment: @RobertN Would you recommend a platform similar to Flash that can more easily interact with the operating system? I am making an imbeded device and I was going to use flash for my ui as it can be used full screen and can be designed in a graphical WYSIWYG Environment. I'm stuck.